# What does the processor do while waiting for a main memory fetch

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Assuming l1 and l2 cache requests result in a miss, does the processor stall until main memory has been accessed?

I heard about the idea of switching to another thread, if so what is used to wake up the stalled thread?

Comment: Maybe that question should go to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My understanding is that a hyperthreaded cpu could perform other tasks while memory is being fetched. Additionally, other threads could perform any number of operations as long as they don't use the bus that is occupied by the memory fetch operation. In practice most memory buses today are serial (is this correct?), so only a single CPU is likely to be able to access main memory at a time.

Comment: *I heard about the idea of switching to another thread* Depending on the language, you can use `std::thread` (in c++) to switch to another thread. The time it takes to move to another thread and the cost of copying over any L1/L2 memory to that thread is likely to exceed the time of a typical cache-line fetch though so I don't think that's an automatic fix.

Comment: @Arman I understand that, what I am really after is the intricacies of modern designs. Assuming out of order memory responses how does the CPU know which is the stalled read? is it some kind of keyed response queue? or prehaps an interrupt from the memory controller? What happens if CPU supports OOE and the commit buffer fills waiting for the read to complete? Can another thread run then? Is space earmarked in the commit buffer for a seperate thread?

Comment: I think this question is better suited to Cs, like Nadeem mentioned. It's also beyond my knowledge. I'm interested to see what the answer is though!

Answer (score 10):

There are many, many things going on in a modern CPU at the same time. Of course anything needing the result of the memory access cannot proceed, but there may be plenty more things to do. Assume the following C code:

```
double sum = 0.0; 
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) sum += a [i];

if (sum > 10.0) call_some_function ();
```

and assume that reading the array a stalls. Since reading a [0] stalls, the addition sum += a [0] will stall. However, the processor goes on performing other instructions. Like increasing i, checking that i < 4, looping, and reading a [1]. This stalls as well, the second addition sum += a [1] stalls - this time because neither the correct value of sum nor the value a [1] are known, but things go on and eventually the code reaches the statement "if (sum > 10.0)".

The processor at this point has no idea what sum is. However it can guess the outcome, based on what happened in previous branches, and start executing the function call_some_function () speculatively. So it continues running, but carefully: When call_some_function () stores things to memory, it doesn't happen yet.

Eventually reading a [0] succeeds, many cycles later. When that happens, it will be added to sum, then a [1] will be added to sum, then a [2], then a [3], then the comparison sum > 10.0 will performed properly. Then the decision to branch will turn out to be correct or incorrect. If incorrect, all the results of call_some_function () are throw away. If correct, all the results of call_some_function () are turned from speculative results into real results.

If the stall takes too long, the processor will eventually run out of things to do. It can easily handle the four additions and one compare that couldn't be executed, but eventually it's too much and the processor must stop. However, on a hyper threaded system, you have another thread that can continue running happily, and at a higher speed because nobody else uses the core, so the whole core still can go on doing useful work.

Comment: I think you picked a good example. This speculative behaviour is something I wasn't aware of. Do you have any good references on this?

Comment: There's an excellent article about the Intel Haswell processors here: http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/ which explains lots of things that a modern processor does to gain speed. The wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution shoulde be helpful.

Comment: Nice refs thanks. Speculative Execution was the magic word I didn't pick up from your original explanation!

Comment: Speculative execution has become quite famous with various vulnerabilities like Spectre and Meltdown

Answer (score 4):

A modern out-of-order processor has a Reorder Buffer (ROB) which tracks all inflight instructions and keeps them in program order. Once the instruction at the head of the ROB is finished, it is cleared from the ROB. Modern ROBs are ~100-200 entries in size.

Likewise, a modern OoO processor has a Load/Store Queue which tracks the state of all memory instructions.

And finally, instructions that have been fetched and decoded, but not yet executed, sit in something called the Issue Queue/Window (or "reservation station", depending on the terminology of the designers and modolo some differences in micro-architecture that are largely irrelevant to this question).  Instructions that are sitting in the Issue Queue have a list of register operands they depend on and whether or not their operands are "busy".  Once all of their register operands are no longer busy, the instruction is ready to be executed and it requests to be "issued".

The Issue Scheduler picks from among the ready instructions and issues them to the Execution Units (this is the part that is out-of-order).

Let's look at the following sequence:

```
addi x1 <- x2 + x3
ld   x2 0(x1)
sub  x3 <- x2 - x4
```

As we can see, the "sub" instruction depends on the previous load instruction (by way of the register "x2"). The load instruction will be sent to memory and miss in the caches.  It may take 100+ cycles for it to return and writeback the result to x2. Meanwhile, the sub instruction will be placed in the Issue Queue, with its operand "x2" being marked as busy. It will sit there waiting for a very, very long time. The ROB will quickly fill up with predicted instructions and then stall. The whole core will grind to a halt and twiddle its thumbs.

Once the load returns, it writes back to "x2", broadcasts this fact to the Issue Queue, the sub hears "x2 is now ready!" and the sub can finally proceed, the ld instruction can finally commit, and the ROB will start emptying so new instructions can be fetched and inserted into the ROB.

---

Obviously , this leads to an idle pipeline as lots of instructions will get backed up waiting for the load to return.  There are a couple of solutions to this.

One idea is to simply switch the entire thread out for a new thread.  In a simplified explanation, this basically means flushing out the entire pipeline, storing out to memory the PC of the thread (which is pointing to the load instruction) and the state of the committed register file (at the conclusion of the add instruction before the load). That's a lot of work to schedule a new thread over a cache miss. Yuck.

Another solution is simultaneous multi-threading. For a 2-way SMT machine, you have two PCs and two architectural register files (i.e., you have to duplicate the architectural state for each thread, but you can then share the micro-architectural resources).   In this manner, once you've fetched and decoded the instructions for a given thread, they appear the same to the backend.  Thus, while the "sub" instruction will sit waiting forever in the Issue Queue for the load to come back, the other thread can proceed ahead.  As the first thread comes to a grinding halt, more resources can be allocated to the 2nd thread (fetch bandwidth, decode bandwidth, issue bandwidth, etc.).  In this manner, the pipeline stays busy by effortlessly filling it with the 2nd thread.

Comment: Is this "simultaneous multithreading" what hyperthreading is about?