# Does a CPU idle after a cache miss until the data is fetched from memory?

Tags: caching, cpu, cpu-architecture

If my CPU attempts to fetch data from my multiple layers of cache and comes up with a catch miss in all of them, does it then simply idle until the required data is fetched from memory or does it execute another instruction until the data has been fetched? Like in a non blocking asynchronous way?

Comment: Memory-level parallelism (hit-under-miss and miss-under-miss) is very important for modern CPUs, even low-power in-order ones unless you get down to something you'd call a microcontroller instead of a CPU.  But especially important for fast CPUs where a cache miss to DRAM is hundreds of clocks (and at 4 instructions per clock that would be a *huge* amount of lost work).  One of the most important things out-of-order exec does is let CPUs hide cache-miss latency more effectively.

Comment: I started writing an answer, but might not finish soon, since out-of-order exec and memory-level parallelism are a lot to explain.  But see https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ and https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/5/, https://agner.org/optimize/ and https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(client).  Also note that caches are often multi-ported, e.g. supporting execution of 2 loads per clock cycle, and commit from the store buffer of 1 older retired store.  And L1i-cache is separate, so instruction-fetch can happen in parallel.

Comment: Also e.g. Haswell has 10 LFBs to track cache lines going in/out of L1d cache, and a 72 entry load buffer (multiple misses to the same line are common, so it makes sense to have lots more than LFBs.  Plus, they're needed even for the few cycles of latency while L1d-hit loads are in flight).  Even in-order CPUs allow memory-level parallelism by scoreboarding loads, so well-optimized code that cares about such CPUs (e.g. ARM) will try to avoid using a load result until several instructions later (to avoid stalls on a cache hit).  Or software-pipelining can hide more load latency w/o OoO exec.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the processor do while waiting for a main memory fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563444/what-does-the-processor-do-while-waiting-for-a-main-memory-fetch)  - it has some pretty good answers.

Comment: See also https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/ re: out-of-order exec's capability of hiding cache miss latency.  CPUs definitely do stall the front-end once the ROB fills, which is normal on an L3 cache miss.  But at least it can have started on (or finished) any independent work it could find after that.

Comment: Yes, you have answered my question more than sufficiently, thank you. :)

Comment: If you think [What does the processor do while waiting for a main memory fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25563444) is an appropriate duplicate, you can flag it yourself to have this question point at that one for future readers.  Or if you think my comments here have important stuff not in the answers there, I could collect them up and post them as an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Modern high-performance processors do not execute instructions one-by-one. Instead, they operate on a window of (possibly several hundreds of) *in-flight* instructions, that are said to be executed [out-of-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution), meaning not necessarily in the program order, but whenever an instruction's input operands are ready.

As instructions are executed and their results become available, subsequent in-flight instructions that depend on those can advance to execution. Otherwise, as in the case of waiting for the data to be loaded from the memory, subsequent instructions cannot advance, and wait in a queue.

Until various resources that keep track of in-flight instructions and results are exhausted, the processor will keep making progress by executing the instructions that do not depend on pending operations.

Some of these resources are:

- [Re-order Buffer (ROB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-order_buffer): a queue that tracks the program order of the instructions, so that in-flight results can be made visible in that order, keeping the appearance of in-order execution (e.g. when you step through the program in a debugger)
- Issue Queue ([Reservation Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservation_station)): a list of instructions waiting for their inputs to become available and to be dispatched to an execution unit
- Physical Registers: When a program updates a register multiple times within the window of execution, each version would be stored in a different physical register, to ensure the correct version is used by subsequent instructions even when executed out-of-order (see [register renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming)).
- Load & store queues/buffers: For tracking load and store instructions and cache misses.

Comment: You're mixing Intel terminology vs. every else's for "issue" vs. "dispatch".  If you're going to say "Issue queue", then you should be using "issue" for sending an instruction (from the RS) to an execution unit.  Intel calls that "dispatch", most other computer-architecture discussion calls that "issue", hence the name "issue queue".  In Intel terminology, where "issue" is copying a uop from the front-end to the back-end (and alloc/rename in program order), those uops from from the IDQ (instruction decode queue).

Comment: Another name for the RS is the "scheduler", although some CPUs have some non-scheduling queueing just for capacity to keep up with the ROB vs. a scheduling part of the queue feeding an execution unit. (e.g. in the FP part of Zen2: https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2#Individual_Core)  And while Intel uses a (mostly) unified scheduler for their big cores, some other designs have per-port scheduling queues.

Comment: And BTW, as discussed in comments, even in-order pipelines (like Cortex-A53) normally scoreboard loads to achieve significant memory-level parallelism, allowing multiple outstanding cache misses, and/or in-flight loads from L1d cache since the latency isn't as low as 1c.  Full out-of-order exec isn't necessary to avoid stalling on cache miss, although if you're doing OoO exec anyway, it gives you memory parallelism, too.  (And can hide more of the cache miss latency more effectively.)

Comment: I doubt that the distinction matters. I used "to dispatch" to mean "to send off/away to a destination", and I personally find it a better match semantically than "to issue".

Comment: Yeah, I prefer the version of the terminology where "issue" = entering the back-end, "dispatch" = sending to execution unit.  But it very much does matter, those terms have specific technical meanings for two different things.  There are lots of synonyms for RS, many of which don't involve the word "issue", so pick some of those like "scheduling queue" or "dispatch queue" if you want to use "dispatch" to talk about what they're queueing for.

Comment: I chose to answer for "modern high-performance processors". Technically you could also talk about SMT and thread-level parallelism.

Comment: SMT isn't particularly relevant (cache misses aren't any more or less special), but switch-on-stall would be relevant; coarse-grained hardware multithreading often treats cache misses specially.  Agreed there's no need to mention that, nor multi-core CPUs where other cores can keep the memory controllers busy.  (Recent Intel Xeons notably need most of their cores busy to saturate their DRAM controllers, since per-core bandwidth is lower than desktops, but there are more DRAM channels.)